# how to counting from data array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, count

i have some data at DB like:

```
qty       item  id  date
0001-0500 abcd  1   2010-06-22
0001-0500 abcd  2   2010-06-22
0001-0500 abcd  3   2010-06-22
```

i want some script can make them order by date and show result :

```
qty : 500 (it means 500-1=500,number 1 read 1-1 = 0)
item : abcd
id : 3 (counting from 1 until 3)
date :2010-06-22

qty    item     id   date
500    abcd     3     2010-06-22
```

i have tried like this:

```
'SELECT qty, item, COUNT(*) FROM inspec GROUP BY date';
```

before use the code above,i still confuse to make changes at :

```
qty       
0001-0500 
0001-0500      =>result become:qty : 500 (it means 500-1=500,number 1 read 1-1 = 0)
0001-0500
```

Comment: If you have no knowledge for this, go and learn. You're not here to be spoonfed.

Comment: a) Sort in the database. Always. b) Make a small script that outputs the results. c) If you can't do b), read a PHP/SQL book.

Comment: Do you even understand the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sorting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sorting-rows.html) and [counting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) can be (and I'd say usually are) done at the database level, using SQL.  Otherwise, there are language constructs that can do the heavy lifting for you, again, called [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

If you're using MySQL, the [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tutorial.html) is a good place to start learning.  For PHP, you might find [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005603) helpful.

Comment: Try LIMIT http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm or WHERE http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/select_where.htm, depending on your requirements.  Maybe:  `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE qty = 500;` or `WHERE qty LIKE '%500';`

Answer (score 0):

> i have tried like this:

```
'SELECT item, COUNT(*) FROM inspec GROUP BY date';
```

If you want qty, shouldn't you SELECT it as well?

```
'SELECT item, COUNT(*), qty FROM inspec GROUP BY date';
```